# How to define a serializer for model with a foreign key (not pointing to a pk field but a unique field)?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I am using django rest-framework

There are two modes as below

```
class Service(ResourceModelBase):
    _id = models.UUIDField(unique=True, null=False, default=uuid.uuid1)
    access_key = models.CharField(max_length=200, unique=True, null=False)
    cluster = models.OneToOneField(Cluster, to_field='_id')

class Cluster(ResourceModelBase):
    _id = models.UUIDField(unique=True, null=False, default=uuid.uuid1)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, unique=True, null=False)
```

The service have a foreign key point to the cluster unique key _id field **please be noticed that _id is not the primary key, it is a unique key. This is 
 important to my later question**.

Then I define a serializer for the service model, so I can create and get the service data.

```
class ServiceSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    cluster_id = serializers.SlugRelatedField(queryset=models.Cluster.objects.all(), slug_field='_id')
    class Meta:
        model = models.RGW
        fields = ('_id', 'access_key', 'cluster_id')
```

Please be notice that I define the **cluster_id as a SlugRelatedField not the PrimaryKeyRelatedField.**

The reason to do so is I want to pass the cluster_id a parameter to create  service.

If  I define cluster_id as primary key related field, the  framework  tend to think the cluster_id foreign key is pointing to a  primary  key column. But in my case it is not.  It is pointing  to a unique key field .

So  I use SlugRelatedField(I `m not sure  if this is the right way to do). But  another  problem shows up.

When  I send data to serializer. The  data  I send  in  is as below:

```
{'cluster_id': 'ef3f70cac9e111e89fd1f000ac192ced', 'access_key': 'aaaa'}
```

But data after being validated by  serailzier is

```
serializer.validated_data
OrderedDict([('access_key', 'aaaa'), ('cluster_id', <Cluster: Cluster object (2)>)])
```

For some reason the cluster_id is  converted to cluster  object. So If I  run

```
 serializer.save(serializer.validated_data)
```

This will cause error.

Of course I could re-write the save method. But I just want to know what  is the best way to do this. I feel I am using the framework  in a  wrong  way

Comment: Did you forget to add `source`? `cluster_id = serializers.SlugRelatedField(queryset=models.Cluster.objects.all(), slug_field='_id', source='cluster')`